How do I perform a deployment via FTP to an Azure App Service?
I need to deploy an Azure App Service on the Azure portal and immediately perform an FTP upload using the FTP credentials. The zip file is located on my computer and needs to be uploaded to the FTP server.
I create the Azure App Service using Azure.Resource Manager and obtain the FTP credentials as follows:
var ftpCredential = await _webSite.GetPublishingCredentialsAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, cancellationToken); ftpUsername = ftpCredential.Value.Data.PublishingUserName; ftpPassword = ftpCredential.Value.Data.PublishingPassword; ftpEndpoint = ftpCredential.Value.Data.ScmUri;
My question is: How can I upload a zip file to the FTP server using code?

"How can I upload a zip file to the FTP server using code?" - Not using System.Net.FtpWebRequest (for reasons too many to list). You'll need to use some supported FTP library - or even just some shell-scripting using Windows' own ftp.exe (it isn't installed by default though).

@Dai Windows' ftp.exe neither supports passive mode nor FTPS, so is it really a recommended option?

@LexLi Wow, ugh - I didn't realise it was that bad, sorry.

I created a simple console application and successfully uploaded a Zip file to Azure App Service via FTP.
Thanks @Dai for the comment.
I've used FluentFTP package in my application.

Install FluentFTP package.

My .csproj:
 <ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="FluentFTP" Version="23.2.5" />
</ItemGroup>

In Program.cs file,

Configure the FTPS credentials (username ,password.

 string ftpUsername = "******"; 
 string ftpPassword = "******"; 


Configure the FTPS endpoint  using only the hostname:

string ftpEndpoint = "[ftp-hostname].ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net"

My Program.cs file:
using System;
using System.IO;
using FluentFTP;
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       string ftpUsername = "******"; 
       string ftpPassword = "******"; 
       string ftpEndpoint = "<ftp-hostname>.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net"; 
       int ftpPort = 21; 
       var client = new FtpClient(ftpEndpoint, ftpUsername, ftpPassword)
       {
           Port = ftpPort,
           EncryptionMode = FtpEncryptionMode.Explicit, 
           DataConnectionType = FtpDataConnectionType.PASV 
       };
       try
       {
           client.Connect();
           Console.WriteLine("Connected successfully.");
           string localFilePath = @"C:\Users\****\Downloads\FTPtest.zip"; 
           string remoteFilePath = "/site/wwwroot/FTPtest.zip"; 
           using (var fileStream = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Open))
           {
               client.Upload(fileStream, remoteFilePath);
               Console.WriteLine("File uploaded successfully.");
           }
       }
       catch (FtpException ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"FTP Error: {ex.Message}");
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
       }
       finally
       {
           if (client.IsConnected)
           {
               client.Disconnect();
           }
       }
   }
}


Enable SCM Basic Auth, FTP Basic auth and FTP state to All allowed  in the configuration section of your Azure App Service


I've successfully uploaded the Zip file to Azure App Service.

In the wwwroot folder of the Kudu console, you can find the uploaded zip file.

